# Calculating TFIDF score for information retrieval system

Tags: python, loops, nlp

I need to build a information retrieval system and I was given a list of queries + a list of abstracts. For each query I need to rank the abstracts based on their relevancy to the words in the query by making two tfidf vectors of equal size, one for the query and one for each abstract in the abstract list.

The only way that I come up with is to first store the query words and their corresponding tfidf score in a dictionary and append the dictionaries in a list. For each word of the dictionaries, I iterate through the list of abstract to check if the word is in the abstract, and if so calculate the tfidf score (it is zero if it does not exist). This way I get the vector of the same size as the query.

However, this algorithm is too slow as it needs to run through the list of abstracts for every word of every query - I don't know if there is a way to improve this?

**Edit:
So I am able to improve the runtime by calculating and storing term frequency and the inverse score beforehand, however, when I try to calculate the cosine similarity, the ranking I get seems to be wrong(most abstracts are still in numerical order) and I am getting an error saying that the length of query array does not match the abstract array at query number 6. I can't seem to find the place where it went wrong?**

```
def inverse_document_frequency(word, abstract_word_list):
    all_num = len(abstract_word_list)
    word_count = 0
    for abstract in abstract_word_list:
        if word in abstract:
            word_count += 1
    return log(all_num / word_count)


def term_frequency(word, doc):
    all_num = sum([doc[key] for key in doc])
    return float(doc[word]) / all_num



query_vectors = []
query_dict = []
for query in query_array:
    query_words = query.split(" ")
    new_list = []
    vector = []
    vector_dict = {}
    for word in query_words:
        if word not in closed_class_stop_words and word.isalpha():
            new_list.append(word)

    for word in new_list:
        tf = term_frequency(word, Counter(new_list))
        idf = inverse_document_frequency(word, new_list)
        tfidf = tf * idf
        vector.append(tfidf)
        vector_dict[word] = tfidf


    query_vectors.append(vector)
    query_dict.append(vector_dict)

abstract_idf_dict = {}
abstract_tf_dict = []

for word in abstract_extend:
    if word not in abstract_idf_dict:
        abstract_idf_dict[word] = inverse_document_frequency(word, abstract_word_list)

for abstract in abstract_word_list:
    tf_dict = {}
    for word in abstract:
        if word not in tf_dict:
            valid = [x for x in abstract if x not in closed_class_stop_words]
            tf_dict[word] = Counter(valid)[word] / len(valid)

    abstract_tf_dict.append(tf_dict)

print(abstract_tf_dict)
all_vector_list = []
for i in range(len(query_dict)):
    vector_list = []
    for k in range(len(abstract_word_list)):
        vector = np.zeros(len(query_dict[i]))
        for j in range(len(query_dict[i])):
            key_list = list(query_dict[i].keys())
            word = key_list[j]
            if word in abstract_word_list[k]:
                tfidf = abstract_tf_dict[k][word] * abstract_idf_dict[word]
                vector[j] = tfidf
        print(vector)
        vector_list.append(vector)

    all_vector_list.append(vector_list)


for i in range(len(query_vectors)):
    rank = []
    query_vector = query_vectors[i]
    for j in range(len(all_vector_list[i])):
        abstract_vector = all_vector_list[i][j]
        cos = dot(query_vector, abstract_vector) / (np.sqrt(dot(query_vector, abstract_vector)) * np.sqrt(dot(query_vector, abstract_vector)))
        rank.append((cos, j))
    rank.sort()
    for k in range(len(rank)):
        print(i, rank[k][1])
```

Comment: You need to precalculate the TFs for all words in an abstract when it is inserted into the system and store them -- this will be quite easy as there won't be that many different words. Then querying becomes much faster.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am able to improve the runtime by storing the term frequency, but there seems to be some issues when I try to rank the abstracts by the cosine similarity score, I was wondering if you could help me check the edit?